# The Imaginary Food Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

I am a food you'd never find or certainly wouldn't eat
I don't exist, and yet I do, now isn't that a feat!
I am a good example of something that is wrong
I'm mentioned in the speech of some but more often heard in song.

**What am I?**

---

*Clue 1*

> Because I am not real it is difficult to say
>  exactly what I am, although a certain Dr Hay
>  would tell you I'm no good because my two ingredients
>  should never mix together if you have any sense.

*Clue 2*

> The best hint I can give you, without my being rude
>  is tell you to work backwards, because I'm not a *literal* food!
>  I certainly *sound* food-like, and I mentioned speech and song
>  If you think about those lines you'll have the answer before long!

*Clue 3*

> I'm very disappointed that you need another clue
>  You really should just have a try, display some "daring do"!
>  So if perhaps you're biting time, afraid, or feeling flustered
>  Please, submit your best attempt, it might just pass mustard!

Comment: Is the answer a single word or more than a word?

Comment: There's some food for thought.

Comment: If music be the food of love...

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay That is a very good question! What if I said it is both?

Comment: I guess it could be [Lopadotemachoselachogaleokranioleipsanodrimhypotrimmatosilphioparaomelitokatakechymenokichlepikossyphophattoperisteralektryonoptekephalliokigklopeleiolagoiosiraiobaphetraganopterygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lopadotemachoselachogaleokranioleipsanodrimhypotrimmatosilphioparaomelitokatakechymenokichlepikossyphophattoperisteralektryonoptekephalliokigklopeleiolagoiosiraiobaphetraganopterygon)

Comment: @fffred Why not answer in an answer rather than a comment? (Although not this answer, because it is wrong)

Comment: @Astralbee, Because I knew it was wrong. I just wanted to give some possible idea.

Comment: @Astralbee the phrase is typically spelled "derring-do" - is your spelling intentional? EDIT: Same with "biting time", the normal phrase is "biding time".

Comment: @CaptainPlanet You might be onto something there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're an:

> eggcorn
>
> Definition: a word or phrase that results from a mishearing or misinterpretation of another, an element of the original being substituted for one that sounds very similar or identical (e.g. tow the line instead of toe the line)

I am a food you'd never find or certainly wouldn't eat

> egg and corn are foods, but an eggcorn is not food

I don't exist, and yet I do, now isn't that a feat!

> An eggcorn is a made-up alternative to the real word(s)
> Also, an eggcorn isn't a real food, but an acorn is ('eggcorn' being an eggcorn for 'acorn')

I am a good example of something that is wrong

> It's an incorrectly heard word or phrase

I'm mentioned in the speech of some but more often heard in song.

> I guess because of how common 'mondegreens' are, which I thought could be the answer, but 'eggcorn' is more food-like

Clue 1:

> All about food-combining, so again, egg + corn

Clue 2:

> Similar to the original responses: sounds like food, heard in speech/song, etc.

Clue 3:

> Several examples of eggcorns:
> "daring do" vs "derring-do"
> "biting time" vs "biding time"
> "pass mustard" vs "pass muster" or "cut the mustard"

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @Astralbee Thanks!  Sorry, it really just wasn't clicking until that last clue, then it all made sense.  I enjoyed it though, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I'm thinking

> Accent

I am a food you'd never find or certainly wouldn't eat

> "Ac'cent" is the brand name of [monosodium glutamate (MSG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monosodium_glutamate) - an ingredient in food that you wouldn't find/eat on its own.

I don't exist, and yet I do, now isn't that a feat!

> People who [speak with accents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_(sociolinguistics)) don't notice their accent, while others not native to the region do

I am a good example of something that is wrong

> An accent, or *accentus*, is a [type of logical fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_accent)

I'm mentioned in the speech of some but more often heard in song.

> Accents exist "in the speech of some", but are [common in music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_(music))

Comment: Sadly incorrect but excellent reasoning. Nobody is going to guess it from only the first two lines.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely a stretch, but for any Futurama fan...

> It could be Slurm! 
> Here's a link with more info about it. http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Slurm

I am a food you'd never find or certainly wouldn't eat

> Of course we can't find it because it's fictional, but even if it were real, I would never eat secretion from the anus of the Wormulon Queen

I don't exist, and yet I do, now isn't that a feat!

> It doesn't really exist, but does exist in a fictional show

I am a good example of something that is wrong

> Slurm is a good representation of real world soft drinks and show how corporations promote them even though they're addictive and bad for you

I'm mentioned in the speech of some but more often heard in song.

> Slurm sounds like slur, which is something some people do when they talk, but usually slurring is intentionally done in songs.

I know it's probably not the answer, but still, food for thought ;-)
Also, the title says an "Imaginary Food" riddle.

Comment: Good attempt, sadly incorrect. First clue has been added.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess it is

> Ambrosia

As,

> It is a food of Gods, not us.

Also,

> It can be heard/ read aloud, but not be seen.

It

> exists, as a type of fungus, food for other living organisms in the food chain.

Not sure about the last part, though.

Comment: Another good attempt, sadly incorrect. First clue has been added.

Answer (score 1):

What about

> A placebo

I am a food you'd never find or certainly wouldn't eat
I don't exist, and yet I do, now isn't that a feat!

> The placebo actually does not contain any active ingredient.

I am a good example of something that is wrong

> Wrong in the sense of having no actual medicine even if advertised

I'm mentioned in the speech of some but more often heard in song.

> I don't get the speech part, but there is a band called placebo

Comment: Another good attempt, sadly incorrect. First clue has been added.

Answer (score 1):

Semi-baseless guess to hopefully spark others.  Are you:
 <strike>Catch-Up?</strike>

EDIT:  New Guess
Are you

> Meter

I am a food you'd never find or certainly wouldn't eat

> Starts with 'Meat'

I don't exist, and yet I do, now isn't that a feat!

> The concept is of meter in poetry and in measurement is intangible.  'Feat' may also be a play on 'Feet' which relates to 'meter' both as a unit of length AND of verse cadence

I am a good example of something that is wrong

> The meter of the riddle is wrong! The syllable count is (15-14-13-15), not to mention natural emphases.

I'm mentioned in the speech of some but more often heard in song.

> 'Meter' can be used for speech patterns (or when talking about distance), but mainly refers to cadence in poems and songs

Clue 2:
I certainly sound food-like, and I mentioned speech and song

> 'Meter' fits the bill here

Clue 3:
Please, submit your best attempt, it might just pass mustard!

> ...You put mustard on Meat?

Comment: Not correct, but very good thinking. Remember the rhyme, the correct answer is a *good example of something that is wrong*. You have an example of something wrong, but is it the best?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is the:

> Coda

I am a food you'd never find or certainly wouldn't eat

> The word is similar to the fish Cod. You would never find the coda as it is not food, but the end of speech or piece of music.

I don't exist, and yet I do, now isn't that a feat!

> In music, a coda isn't exact, but rather has an unspecified length. It could be a few bars or a whole part

I am a good example of something that is wrong

I'm mentioned in the speech of some but more often heard in song.

> The main reason I chose the coda in the first place. It is generally used more in music to conclude a piece or movement, but is sometimes mentioned in speech as the sound that follows the vowel in a syllable

> Apologies if this is completely wrong, I'm not much of a music expert!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are...

> A clam?

Reasoning:

> Clam is an out-of-tune note. It sounds like food but in the context of musical slang it’s a mistake.